# Merging to two API calls into the same object with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I am making a table of data that has users. One of the details in each row is their online availability. To do this I need to call two APIs (one for users and one for online availability). The online availability call needs to be called continuously at setintervals to make it update live. I am very confused about how and where to do this. I have merged the two API's by matching their Id's, but I do not know how to constantly call second API without calling the first continuously, as it would use alot of memory. Also I dont know where to do this within redux. Do i do it in the action? reducer? and why? I want this API state to be stored in the store so I can access this merged API across all components of the APP.

```
// action files

export const getUsers = ()=> async dispatch =>{
    const usersResponse = await axios.get(users);
    const userData = usersResponse.data.result;
    dispatch({
        type: GET_USERS,
        payload: userData
    })
}

export const getAvailability = () => async dispatch =>{
    const availabilityResponse = await axios.get(availability);
    const availabilityData = availabilityResponse.data.result;
    dispatch({
        type: GET_AVAILABILITY,
        payload: availabilityData
    })
}


// reducers 

initial state = {
  getUsers: [],
  getAvailability: []
}

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_USERS:
            return {
                ...state,
                getUsers: action.payload
            };
        case GET_AVAILABILITY:
            return {
                ...state,
                getAvailability: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}


//component


  async componentDidMount() {
        await this.props.getUsers();
        await this.props.getAvailability();

        let availabilityObject = {};
        this.props.availability.map(availability => {
           availabilityObject[availability.uuid] = availability;
        });
        if (typeof this.props.users != "undefined") {
            this.props.users.map(user => {
                user.availability = availabilityObject[user.uuid];
            });
        }
          console.log(this.props.users) 
//this doesn't show a merged Object of users and availability
    }



    const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
        users: state.getUsers,
        status: state.getAvailability
    });
```

Comment: I believe altogether it is a data flow design issue than a specific question. You could call your api from anywhere but after you get the data all you need to make sure you dispatch the right action. `await` might be blocking your code. I'd not make that heavy use of it.

Comment: with `GET_USERS` you could update the state and with `GET_AVAILABILITY` you can simply update the field of target user. If you maintain a different place for them then you could setup a different reducer, in some situation that would be better.

Comment: to achieve modularity and maintenability, ditch the await in action creator. Use a middleware. It's not very difficult to write one. If you don't have time for that you can checkout `redux-api-middleware`.